# How to determine the type of items in classes derived from ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, attached-properties, itemcontainergenerator

I am implementing an Attached Property for the ItemsControl.
Faced with such a task that I cannot solve.
I climb from the UI element in the ItemTemplate along the visual tree to the ItemsControl. There is no problem with that.
But I also need to define the type used to generate items in the ItemsControl.
And this type is also different in different classes derived from ItemsControl.

Let's say for ListBox can apply the following code

```
    public static bool GetIndexOn(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        int? index = (int?)element.GetValue(IndexProperty);
        if (index == null)
        {
            FrameworkElement parent = element;

            // Search ListBoxItem
            // But I need to find any type used to generate Item
            while (!(parent is System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem || parent == null))
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as FrameworkElement;

            if (parent == null)
                return false;

            // Saving the ListBoxItem
            System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem)parent;


            // Search ItemsControl
            while (!(parent is ItemsControl || parent == null))
                parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) as FrameworkElement;

            if (parent == null)
                return false;

            // Saving the ListBox
            ItemsControl listBox = (ItemsControl)parent;

            // Retrieving and storing index of ListBoxItem in ListBox
            index = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(listBoxItem);
            element.SetValue(IndexPropertyKey, index);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of this attached property? Do you know that ItemsControl has an ItemContainerGenerator property, which helps to map items and their indexes to container elements?

Comment: @Clemens, Yes I know.
I am using **ItemContainerGenerator** in code.
In the parameters of its methods, you must pass the item from the **ItemsControl**.
I need to find from the UI element nested in **Item** from the **ItemsComtrol** collection in which item it is nested.
If know its type, then it is easy to do.
It is necessary to climb the visual tree to the desired type.
But, derived from **ItemsControl** use different types and I don't know how to determine which one.
My question is connected with this.

Comment: @Clemens,
Meaning: A simple ability to find the index of an **Item** from the **ItemTemplate**.
This is done more for teaching, but not for practical use.
Part of the implementation is shown.
I have not posted the code, in my opinion, that is not related to the topic.
But if it's not clear without it, then write - I'll post it.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about by "item". But if it is a member item of source collection bound to `ItemsSource` property of the ItemsControl, why `ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer` method would not help you? It's just out of curiosity.

Comment: @emoacht, I apologize for the ambiguity!
I meant UI elements inside ItemsControl.
They are created by the ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride() method.
In ItemsControl, this method returns ContentPresenter.
In ListBox - ListBoxItem, in ComboBox - ComboBoxItem.
In general, there can be an element of any type.
Since I am walking through the visual tree, I need to understand when I get to this element.

Comment: @EldHasp I see. I think it is possible to somehow fulfill your need but I don't know the whole picture of your project.

Comment: Take a look at the sample code.
The line with the comment "But I need to find any type used to generate Item".
There I am looking for ListBoxItem and the solution works for ListBox.
But I need to make a universal solution for any item derived from ItemsControl.
If I can determine what type I need to look for, I just need to specify it in this line.